# Height of the prints are always larger

Tags: marlin, creality-ender-3, ultimaker-cura, pla

This problem is driving me crazy, no, seriously speaking. I bought this printer this week and started to calibrate for accurate dimensions. I printed the one-and-only calibration cube (20x20x20 also a 10x10x10) and well, the dimensions for the X & Y axis are perfect, but the Z-axis is a big problem, almost 1.5 mm bigger than expected.

I tried everything in order to resolve this issue, I checked to see if the steps are correctly calibrated using a ruler and moving my extruder up and down, precise as you expected, no weird sounds coming from the Z-axis and stepper while printing. I calibrated the E-Step, also the bed leveling is done automatically using the BLTouch probe. Also I want to mention that the first layer is perfect (took time to calibrate this too).

I am using Cura for slicing using the default profile for the Ender 3 Pro, Premium PLA, 210 °C for the first layer & 200 °C for the rest, 50 °C bed temperature.

I will leave here some photos, perhaps somebody could give me an idea.

As you can see from the images the Z-axis is scaled-up perfectly. This difference is about 1.5 mm for both cubes (the one with 20 mm & 10 mm).

**Has anyone encountered this type of problem before?**

**EDIT:**
I will attach some pictures with the first layer. Right now I observe some wobbling in the Z axis and saw that the printer is not perfect laid on the table, one corner was lifted. So I tried to flatten. Waiting for the test print.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If your output is, for example, 5% too tall, please reduce your steps per mm in the Z by 5% and retest; let us know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The idea is that if I move the Z axis manual the distance travelled is perfect all the time. Just when is printing this problem occurs. I will try to compensate using the steps, but I don’t think that this is causing the problem.

Comment: Since the 10mm and 20mm cubes are both off by the same amount, it is not a matter of scaling.

Comment: What does the first layer surface look like?

Comment: The first layer is looking incredible, no squeezing at all, I didn’t use any adhesive for the cubes. That’s what is driving me crazy ☹️. Right now I am not near the printer. But I could update the post with the image to see for yourself.

Comment: You didn't mention anything about reviewing output g-code file. Have you review it? Nothing suspicious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since nobody had any idea what cause the problem, I investigated for a full week.

The problem is related to **Fade Height** and .... a **warp bed**, since I have ABL (Auto Bed Levelling) and Fade Height enable. The compensation was way too big, something like -1.4 or bigger.

So, after I bought a new glass bed and set the fade height to 0 the problem is gone and the prints are looking normal, like -.2 mm or -.3mm in heights.